# result from a function printing twice when function is exported to a different JS file

Tags: javascript

I had a function that counts the number of lines in a file and prints out the result and it works fine. I also have a separate js file I imported to my first js file with a rough addition function which also works fine.

The first issue I had is when I run my first js file it prints out `count` twice. This is occurring when I import the first js file to the second js file. When I comment out the require on the second js file the `lineCount()` function correctly runs and `count` is printed only once as it is supposed to.

Why is the result `count` printing twice when I require the js file in a separate file and how can I fix it to only print the result once while the require statement is still there?

My second question is when I run my first js file I get `TypeError: add is not a function` even though I exported add from my second js files and called it properly `fun1.add()`. Why is the function not running and how can I fix it?

```js
const fun1 = require(PATH to second js file);

const fs = require('fs')

function lineCount() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let count = 0;
        fs.createReadStream('./classifiedYtData.txt')
            .on("data", (buffer) => {
                let idx = -1;
                count--;
                do {
                    idx = buffer.indexOf(10, idx + 1);
                    count++;
                } while (idx !== -1);
            }).on("end", () => {
                resolve(count);
                console.log(count)
            }).on("error", reject);
            
    });
}

lineCount()
fun1.add()

module.exports = {
  lineCount,
}
```

```js
const fun2 = require(PATH to first js file);

function add() {
  const a = 3;
  const b = 5;
  console.log(a+b);
}

module.exports = {
  add,
}
```

Comment: Requiring or importing a Javascript file **runs the code in the file**.

Comment: yeah, but why duplicate it how can I only make it run once.@connexo

Comment: Don't make calls in your modules. Instead, require both modules and run your functions from there.

Comment: I already tried that the function won't run until called from the exported page. And once called from the exported page the result prints twice.@connexo

Comment: and when I call the function on the second js file in which I required my main js I get error: lineCount is not a function hence my second question. @connexo

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the result count printing twice when I require the js file in a separate file and how can I fix it to only print the result once while the require statement is still there?

Regarding printings: the first one is from `lineCount` , the second one from `fun1.add()`

Requiring the module in JavaScript will run the code inside it.
When you run the first file:

The second file is requiring. So it goes into the file and begins to run it. When it begins - the first file is requiring and it begins to run it again and so on. It called `cycle dependencies`. You should avoid it. So, just remove `const fun2 = require(PATH to first js file);` from the second file cause I don't see any usage of it.

FYI: there are no errors if you call the first file. But there is the error you mentioned when the second file is called and the reason is a cycle dependency.